# AVCaptureSession video orientation iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avcapturesession, avmutablecomposition

I am capturing video using AVCaptureSession. The problem is i don't understand the whole logic behind video orientation. I set video orientation like this:

```
AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection = [self.movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[captureConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
```

So i record the video and show a preview to the user, but the video orientation is always sideways. And i need it to always be portrait.
I found some similar problems on SO but didn't get to find a solution.

The code i'm using to record a video:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.captureSession = session;
AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (VideoDevice)
{
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
    self.videoInputDevice = input;
    if (!error)
    {
        if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:self.videoInputDevice])
            [self.captureSession addInput:self.videoInputDevice];
    }
}

AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
if (audioInput)
    [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];

[self.previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
self.previewLayer = nil;

[self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession]];
[self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput;

Float64 TotalSeconds = kDefaultRecordingTime;
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;
CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);
self.movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
self.movieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;
self.movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;

if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.movieFileOutput])
    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.movieFileOutput];

[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];

if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720])
    [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720];

CGRect layerRect = [self.recordingView bounds];
[self.previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
[self.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                           CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
[self.recordingView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];

[self.recordingView bringSubviewToFront:self.recordButton];
[self.recordingView bringSubviewToFront:self.frontCameraButton];

AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection = [self.movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[captureConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];


[self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
[self.captureSession startRunning];
```

I then record another video and mix it using AVMutableComposition. But all my videos are rotated horizontally. I don't do any rotations when mixing it with avmutablecomposition.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me directions what to do or maybe even see what is wrong in the code it would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mayur i've checked that and tried everything from this already, doesn't help. It seems that whatever i set my recording is still rotated horizontally. I'm trying to set the orientation when composing a track with AVMutableComposition.

Comment: are you taking video in portrait mode ?

Comment: @Mayur yes i'm taking them in portrait mode. Then i use AVMutableComposition to add music, really simple stuff with no rotations or anything. But my video is horizontal. I save it to iphone and send it to my mac and it's the same on mac. Rotated horizontally. Banging my head on this for three days already :/

Comment: kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this to resolve orientation issue:

First of all remove this 2 lines from your code :

```
AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection = [self.movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[captureConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
```

Now in add this code at the same place :

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

for ( AVCaptureConnection *connection in [movieFileOutput connections] )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", connection);
    for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts] )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", port);
        if ( [[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
        }
    }
}

if([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) // **Here it is, its always false**
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
}
```

**Edit :**

- Just add my code at very last.

I hope it will work.

Comment: it's still the same :/

Comment: @Lukas do a last attempt & try to add my code at very last after this line
[self.captureSession startRunning];

Comment: @Lukas ohh it looks like critical issue. I will have to try it out on device.

Comment: i've chosen different library for that, couldn't solve it :/